# Alternateur Diagram

Tags: diagrams

I would like to make this diagram.

[image: Alternateur Diagram]

I can find the good program can you help me

Comment: welcome to tex.se! (la)tex nor its packages is nod design for technical drawings. however, with a lot patient work you probably will be able draw your illustration. for example with using `tikz` packages. *note*: this site is not service "we will do your task instead of you. show us, what you try so far and where you stuck ...

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to TeX.SE! The purpose of this site is to share codes, not to let others draw things (I am not saying that this is what you are asking). So I take your post as the question how one may draw repeatedly the same objects with different dimensions, orientations and colors at different positions in 3d.

1. As for the repeated objects, one way is to define styles that insert the appropriate paths. The answer below has proposal for such styles for horizontal plates (`hplate`), vertical plates (`vplate`), cylinder bodies and cylinder tops.
2. `tikz-3dplot` allows one to obtain orthographic projections of 3d space. However, Ti*k*Z does not have a 3d engine, so one has to draw these objects in the appropriate order.

Using these tools, here is a proposal for your left figure, the right one and the annotations are left as an exercise. (I really do not enjoy punching in texts from a screen shot, the more so if I am not fluent in the language so that I have to remember some words letter by letter.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{50}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RadiusPlate}{3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\RadiusCylinder}{2}
\begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,hplate/.style n args={4}{%
insert path={ % #1=angle, #2=radius, #3=width/2, #4=z
({#3*sin(#1)},{-#3*cos(#1)},#4) -- 
({#2*cos(#1)+#3*sin(#1)},{#2*sin(#1)-#3*cos(#1)},#4) --
({#2*cos(#1)-#3*sin(#1)},{#2*sin(#1)+#3*cos(#1)},#4) --
({-#3*sin(#1)},{#3*cos(#1)},#4) -- cycle}},
vplate/.style n args={5}{%
insert path={% % #1=angle, #2=radius, #3=width/2, #4=z_bottom, #5=z_top
({#2*cos(#1)+#3*sin(#1)},{#2*sin(#1)-#3*cos(#1)},#4) --
({#2*cos(#1)+#3*sin(#1)},{#2*sin(#1)-#3*cos(#1)},#5) --
({#2*cos(#1)-#3*sin(#1)},{#2*sin(#1)+#3*cos(#1)},#5) --
({#2*cos(#1)-#3*sin(#1)},{#2*sin(#1)+#3*cos(#1)},#4) -- cycle
}},
cylinder body/.style n args={3}{insert path={ % #1=radius, #2=z_bottom, #3=z_top
 plot[samples=51,variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi-180,smooth] 
  ({#1*cos(\x)},{#1*sin(\x)},#2)
   -- plot[samples=51,variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi-180:\tdplotmainphi,smooth] 
  ({#1*cos(\x)},{#1*sin(\x)},#3)
  -- cycle
}},
cylinder top/.style n args={2}{insert path={ % #1=radius, #2=z
plot[samples=51,variable=\x,domain=\tdplotmainphi:\tdplotmainphi+360,smooth]
  ({#1*cos(\x)},{#1*sin(\x)},#2)
}}] 
\foreach \Z in {0,-90}
{\draw[fill=cyan,hplate={\Z}{3.2}{0.2}{-0.1}];}
 \foreach \Z in {0,0.4,...,2}
 {\draw[thick,fill=orange,cylinder top={\RadiusPlate}{\Z}]; }
\foreach \Z in {20,-70,-160,-220,-280}
 {\draw[fill=cyan,hplate={\Z}{3.2}{0.3}{2.1}];}
\foreach \Z in {-220,-280}
 {\draw[fill=cyan,vplate={\Z}{3.2}{0.3}{2.1}{4.5}];}
\draw[fill=cyan,cylinder top={0.5}{2.1}];
\draw[thick,fill=purple!80,cylinder body={\RadiusCylinder}{3}{4}];
\draw[thick,fill=purple!60,cylinder top={\RadiusCylinder}{4}];
\foreach \Z in {20,-70,-160}
 {\draw[fill=cyan,vplate={\Z}{3.2}{0.3}{2.1}{4.5}];}
\foreach \Z in {0,-90}
 {\draw[fill=cyan,vplate={\Z}{3.2}{0.2}{-0.1}{2.5}];}
\draw[thick,fill=cyan!40,cylinder body={0.25*\RadiusCylinder}{4}{5.5}];
\draw[thick,fill=cyan!40,cylinder body={0.5*\RadiusCylinder}{5.5}{6}];
\draw[thick,fill=cyan!20,cylinder top={0.5*\RadiusCylinder}{6}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And sometimes when one is done with answers like this, one gets really helpful comments like [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469325/parallelepiped-inscribed-in-cylinder/469392?noredirect=1#comment1181792_469392). To anyone tempted to make a comment in this direction: do you really think this is how we should treat each other on this site?